# Getting error "Generic parameter 'Label' could not be inferred" with SwiftUI tutorial code

Tags: swiftui

I'm working through this SwiftUI tutorial here:
https://developer.apple.com/tutorials/swiftui/handling-user-input

And on Step 3 of the section "Adopt the Model Object in Your View", I get this error on the Toggle statement in line 16: "Generic parameter 'Label' could not be inferred."

My code is identical to that provided in the tutorial:

```
import SwiftUI

struct LandmarkList: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var userData: UserData

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List {
                Toggle(isOn: $userData.showFavoritesOnly) {
                    Text("Favorites Only")
                }
                ForEach(userData.landmarkData) { landmark in
                    if !self.userData.showFavoritesOnly || landmark.isFavorite {
                        NavigationLink(destination: LandmarkDetail(landmark: landmark)) {
                            LandmarkRow(landmark: landmark)
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            .navigationBarTitle(Text("Landmarks"))
        }
    }
}

struct LandmarkList_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ForEach(["iPhone SE", "iPhone XS Max"], id: \.self) { deviceName in
            LandmarkList()
                .previewDevice(PreviewDevice(rawValue: deviceName))
                .previewDisplayName(deviceName)
        }
    }
}
```

When I look at the code provided in the "Complete" folder, I see its nearly identical, except that the userData variable is made private—which I added to my "StartingPoint" version, though I can't imagine why it'd make a difference, and of course it still gives the same error and won't build. I can build and run the Complete version, so clearly the message about requiring a Generic parameter is wrong and it must have to do with something else like how the project is configured in settings.

I remember getting stuck earlier this summer with a similar issue in a different part of the tutorial, and found a post where someone explained why code would work in one project and not another, but I can't find that post now.

Is anyone familiar with this issue? Is there something else I need to understand about how to configure my project before I can reference an observable object in a toggle control in my view like this?

Comment: Are you running it in Simulator or in Preview Mode? For the Preview Mode you need to add `.environmentObject(UserData())` under the `ForEach()` in your `LandmarkList_Previews` struct

Comment: Thanks—that was it. I wasn't out of the woods until I also added .environmentObject(self.userData) under the LandmarkDetail(landmark: landmark) in the List

Comment: If you want to put your explanation in an answer I'll mark it as the answer @krjw

Comment: And if anyone can explain if there's a good reason why this question has been downvoted, I'd appreciate it. I would think getting an erroneous build error on code that was provided in the official Apple tutorial would warrant seeking help here. If I did something wrong, please let me know what it was

Comment: I always get weird errors when developing with SwiftUI... I guess they will improve the Error Messages in the future but for now we need to figure it out on our own :)

Comment: Got this same error for a totally different issue

Comment: when following the tutorial you were instructed to user the property landmarks not landmarkData and so changing the line                

'ForEach(userData.landmarkData) { landmark in'

to 

'ForEach(userData.landmarks) { landmark in'

Solved it for me. (after the changes to the preview of course)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So as I mentioned in the comments: Just add `.environmentObject(UserData())` under the `ForEach()` in your `LandmarkList_Previews` struct.

That would result in:

```
import SwiftUI

struct LandmarkList: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var userData: UserData

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List {
                Toggle(isOn: $userData.showFavoritesOnly) {
                    Text("Favorites Only")
                }
                ForEach(userData.landmarkData) { landmark in
                    if !self.userData.showFavoritesOnly || landmark.isFavorite {
                        NavigationLink(destination: LandmarkDetail(landmark: landmark)
                            .environmentObject(self.userData)
                        ) {
                            LandmarkRow(landmark: landmark)
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            .navigationBarTitle(Text("Landmarks"))
        }
    }
}

struct LandmarkList_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ForEach(["iPhone SE", "iPhone XS Max"], id: \.self) { deviceName in
            LandmarkList()
                .previewDevice(PreviewDevice(rawValue: deviceName))
                .previewDisplayName(deviceName)
        }.environmentObject(UserData())
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you explain why we'd call `environmentObject()` on the `ForEach` rather than on the `LandmarkList` inside the `ForEach`?

Answer (score 1):

I had the exact same problem today and [Ravi Mishra's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58821495/getting-error-generic-parameter-label-could-not-be-inferred-with-swiftui-tut#comment109607533_60461566) comment resolved the issue for me (kudos to you). It must've been an autocomplete mistake.

`ForEach(userData.landmarkData)` should instead be `ForEach(userData.landmarks)`

Answer (score 0):

I bothered my head about this tutorial for a week, went line by line through it twice by downloading the tutorial files again.  I made sure that every character of my work in the tutorial matched every character of the completed project--twice--and still that nasty error message popped up as soon as I entered the final code.  Stack Overflow was my last stop; when I read the solution was to include '.environmentObject(UserData())', I went right to my code to add it but it was already there!
Out of pure desperation, I decided to copy the (exact same) code for the body from the source of the completed project to the source in my tutorial project.  The error disappeared.
I think @krjw has a point.

Comment: I  was stuck on the same. I think the code what you were using was""ForEach(userData.landmarkData)" instead you should have used " ForEach(userData.landmarks)".